# Failing to parameterize a download url in powershell script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, nexus

I am trying to download artifacts from a nexus server. So i forged the below ps script.

```
$Webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Nexusurl  = "http://ec2-54-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/bar" + "/" + ${BUILD_NUMBER} + "/" + ${ProjectName}.zip
$Webclient.DownloadFile($Nexusurl, 'c:\webcontent.zip')
```

I have 2 things as parameter in the PS. The jenkin's BUILD_NUMBER and the ProjectName. These 2 are set as a parameter in the jenkins job. The `ProjectName` is the name of the artifact on nexus server which is to be downloaded.

The command executes without an error. But the file `c:\webcontent.zip` is showing as invalid, while trying to decompress. So, i think the URL ($Nexusurl) is constructed incorrectly while executing the PS. Adding an echo like this

`echo $Nexusurl`

revealed that the URL is missing the parameters. They are not substituted in the `$Nexusurl`

```
http://ec2-54-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/bar//
```

What am i doing incorrect that the parameters are not substituted in the URL. I have tried a lot of combinations but unsuccessful so far!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a formatted string to define `$Nexusurl` as such:

```
$Nexusurl  = "http://ec2-54-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/bar/{0}/{1}.zip" -f $ENV:BUILD_NUMBER, $ENV:ProjectName
```

This will sub in the first argument where `{0}` is, and the second argument where `{1}` is.

Answer (score 0):

One more push and i think i am there. The final PS script looks like this:

```
$Webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Nexusurl  = "http://ec2-54-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/bar" + "/" + $ENV:BUILD_NUMBER + "/" + $ENV:ProjectName
echo $Nexusurl
$Webclient.DownloadFile($Nexusurl, 'c:\webcontent.zip')
```

But still not sure why i can place an extension of .zip after the `$ENV:ProjectName` .. So, for the time being, i am using the parameter with the .zip extention